# How to write an online screen name in dialogue?

Tags: dialogue, formatting, screenwriting

Might be a bit nitpicky - but I really want to get the formatting correct - especially because this is one of the first lines in the script. The screen name is: ArgyleMan29

Like this?

JACK:
Online I’m ArgyleManTwentyNine.

Or

JACK:
Online I’m Argyle Man Twenty Nine.

Or

JACK:
Online I’m Argyle-Man-Twenty-Nine.

Italics?

Thanks!

Comment: Or just as you say "ArgyleMan29" it is all fine as long as your reader instantly identifies it with an online screen name. I suggest using actual numbers.

Comment: Saying that you want to get the format "correct" is essentially meaningless as a general statement.  There is no single authority which determines which format is correct and which incorrect in this instance.  If you're submitting a manuscript for consideration, the receiving institution will likely have a style guide.  Comply with that and if this isn't covered (it likely won't be) then use your best judgement based on what actually is covered.

Answer (score 5):

Names should always be written as they actually are. Because they are names, unless of course, the pronunciation of the name or the format makes it difficult for the reader to understand or convey it correctly. In that case, the first time it's used (not in dialogue, but in notes or direction) the pronunciation should be dealt with.

ArgyleMan29 would likely be exactly what it would look like on a computer screen. I don't find it difficult to read, especially with the in-capitalization giving the pronunciation clarity. Do not type out the numbers in words.

No need for italics, it's a proper name that happens to be online, indicating a person. I have never seen a correct instance where a person's name was italicized--nicknames or screen names, unless to differentiate fonts as a style flair.

This is how it should look:

JACK: Online I'm ArgyleMan29.

Answer (score 4):

As for whether or not to write out numbers in dialogue, that specific topic is covered in [this](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/16713/how-do-i-write-numbers-in-dialogue) post.

The general consensus seems to be that simple numbers should be written out, and that longer or awkward numbers (such as phone numbers), or numbers used repeatedly, can remain.

The thinking behind this is that people don't *say* numbers—although, logically, I'm not sure it's clear that people say *letters* either. But that's a different debate.

The short answer is that there is no rule, but there do seem to be common and less common styles.

I think that in the case of a screen name that includes text and a number, and which is used repeatedly, there could be little objection to using the number.

As a reference, look at the dialogue in the [*Star Wars* script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html) (which I'm assuming is legitimate):

```
            LUKE
This R2 unit has a bad motivator.
Look!
```

Based on that, and the other answer, I think it would be fine to simply use the screen name exactly as you have it: `ArgyleMan29`.

---

As an interesting side note, I found something else in the *Star Wars* script. The first time that the robots are introduced in direction, their names are given phonetically:

> An explosion rocks the ship as two robots, Artoo-Detoo (R2-D2) and See-Threepio (C-3PO) struggle to make their way through the shaking, bouncing passageway.

I'm not sure if this is common or not. I can't really see it adding value to the director. (Aside, perhaps, from pointing out that it's an *oh* and not a *zero* in the latter name.)

Answer (score 2):

This is my opinion; the first option, capcase run together, is preferable. But sites vary, some let you use spaces in your name, some won't let you mix cases, etc.

Edit: I skimmed over the fact that 29 is not written out in the user name, I agree with Totumus's comment; it should be used as numbers, not written out.